# jQuery Pagination Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, jquery-pagination

Hopefully this is something that will be easy to remedy.  I'm having a bit of an issue understanding the [jQuery Pagination](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination) plugin.

Essentially, all I am trying to do is load a PHP file, and then paginate the results.  I'm attempting to go off their example, but I am not yielding the results I'm looking for.

Here's the JavaScript:

```
 function pageselectCallback(page_index, jq){
            var new_content = $('#hiddenresult div.result:eq('+page_index+')').clone();
            $('#Searchresult').empty().append(new_content);
            return false;
        }
        function initPagination() {
            var num_entries = $('#hiddenresult div.result').length;
            // Create pagination element
            $("#Pagination").pagination(num_entries, {
                num_edge_entries: 2,
                num_display_entries: 8,
                callback: pageselectCallback,
                items_per_page:3
            });
         }      
        $(document).ready(function(){      
            $('#hiddenresult').load('load.php', null, initPagination);
        });
```

Here's my HTML (after the PHP has been loaded):

```
        <div id="Pagination" class="pagination"> </div>
        <br style="clear:both;" />
        <div id="Searchresult"> </div>

       <div id="hiddenresult" style="display:none;"> 
         <div class="result">Result #1</div>
         <div class="result">Result #2</div>
         <div class="result">Result #3</div>
         <div class="result">Result #4</div>
         <div class="result">Result #5</div>
         <div class="result">Result #6</div>
         <div class="result">Result #7</div>
       </div>
```

Basically, I am trying to show "3" items per page, but this is not working.  I'm assuming that somewhere, I am going to need to create a for loop in my JS, but I'm confused on how to do so.  [The documentation can be found here](http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/lib/jquery_pagination/README).

Comment: Hey men I have same issues as yours But i tried doing all script here but i've made it through
Hope this help to your problem
http://bit.ly/free-pagination it's only custom scripting not plugsin but really useful

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't even need to use a for loop, just use jQuery's `slice()` method and a bit of math.

I've hosted a working demo on JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/upuwe (Editable via http://jsbin.com/upuwe/edit)

Here's the modified code:

```
var pagination_options = {
  num_edge_entries: 2,
  num_display_entries: 8,
  callback: pageselectCallback,
  items_per_page:3
}
function pageselectCallback(page_index, jq){
  var items_per_page = pagination_options.items_per_page;
  var offset = page_index * items_per_page;
  var new_content = $('#hiddenresult div.result').slice(offset, offset + items_per_page).clone();
  $('#Searchresult').empty().append(new_content);
  return false;
}
function initPagination() {
  var num_entries = $('#hiddenresult div.result').length;
  // Create pagination element
  $("#Pagination").pagination(num_entries, pagination_options);
}
```

Comment: Brian, that was awesome.  Thanks very much for pointing out the slice() method!

Comment: @brainpeiris i am struggling with the pagination plugin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505435/good-jquery-pagination-plugin-to-use-with-json-data and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523075/generate-page-numbers-using-javascript-jquery