# Suggestion for a good jquery pagination plugin for a complex table

Tags: jquery, plugins, pagination

I have a table with the following complex structure....

```
<table>
  <tr> // 1st row
     <td>
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>

         <table>
             <thead>
                <tr>
                </tr> etc...
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                 <tr>

                 </tr> etc etc...
             </tbody>
         </table>
     </td>
  </tr> // end 1st row

 <tr> //2nd row
     <td>
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>

         <table>
             <thead>
                <tr>
                </tr> etc...
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                 <tr>

                 </tr> etc etc...
             </tbody>
         </table>
     </td>
  </tr> //end 2nd row

etc etc etc....
</table>
```

Now i need a plugin so that i can paginate the rows of this table.... 
I've thought about datatables and tablesorter plugins but theyr're not compatible for the above structure... Any suggestions on which one i can use...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery Pagination Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination)

and a demo at

[jQuery Pagination Plugin Demo](http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm)

with a good set of configuration options.

Comment: Tried this too... doesn't work in IE6... and also if i set the "items_per_page" option to more than 1 it gets buggy....!!

Comment: Rot in hell ie6. As a developer I've stopped wasting countless hours on that browser. A "you should upgrade your browser" overlay works nicely.

Comment: And here is a neat tip...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523163/jquery-pagination-plugin/1523265#1523265