# Good jQuery pagination plugin to use with JSON data

Tags: jquery, plugins, pagination

I am looking for a good jQuery pagination plugin to use in my aspx page.

I have the following parameters.
`currentpage, pagesize, TotalRecords, NumberofPages`. I would like my plugin to do the same as Stack Overflow paging.

**EDIT:**
It should paginate through JSON data.

Similar to this,

[image: pager]

I use my JSON data and iterating with jQuery

```
var jsonObj = jQuery.parseJSON(HfJsonValue);
    for (var i = jsonObj.Table.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var employee = jsonObj.Table[i];
        $('<div class="resultsdiv"><br /><span class="resultName">' + employee.Emp_Name + '</span><span class="resultfields" style="padding-left:100px;">Category&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.Desig_Name + '</span><br /><br /><span id="SalaryBasis" class="resultfields">Salary Basis&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.SalaryBasis + '</span><span class="resultfields" style="padding-left:25px;">Salary&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.FixedSalary + '</span><span style="font-size:110%;font-weight:bolder;padding-left:25px;">Address&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.Address + '</span></div>').insertAfter('#ResultsDiv');
    }
```

There are 25 divs in my page. As a result, how do I show the first five divs in page `1` and so on?

My `HfJsonValue` contains the following json data

```
{
    "Table": [{
        "Emp_Id": "3",
        "Identity_No": "",
        "Emp_Name": "Jerome",
        "Address": "Madurai",
        "Date_Of_Birth": "",
        "Desig_Name": "Supervisior",
        "Desig_Description": "Supervisior of the Construction",
        "SalaryBasis": "Monthly",
        "FixedSalary": "25000.00"
    }, {
        "Emp_Id": "4",
        "Identity_No": "",
        "Emp_Name": "Mohan",
        "Address": "Madurai",
        "Date_Of_Birth": "",
        "Desig_Name": "Acc ",
        "Desig_Description": "Accountant",
        "SalaryBasis": "Monthly",
        "FixedSalary": "200.00"
    }, {
        "Emp_Id": "5",
        "Identity_No": "",
        "Emp_Name": "Murugan",
        "Address": "Madurai",
        "Date_Of_Birth": "",
        "Desig_Name": "Mason",
        "Desig_Description": "Mason",
        "SalaryBasis": "Weekly",
        "FixedSalary": "150.00"
    }, {
        "Emp_Id": "6",
        "Identity_No": "",
        "Emp_Name": "Ram",
        "Address": "Madurai",
        "Date_Of_Birth": "",
        "Desig_Name": "Mason",
        "Desig_Description": "Mason",
        "SalaryBasis": "Weekly",
        "FixedSalary": "120.00"
    }, {
        "Emp_Id": "7",
        "Identity_No": "",
        "Emp_Name": "Raja",
        "Address": "Madurai",
        "Date_Of_Birth": "",
        "Desig_Name": "Mason",
        "Desig_Description": "Mason",
        "SalaryBasis": "Weekly",
        "FixedSalary": "135.00"
    }, {
        "Emp_Id": "8",
        "Identity_No": "",
        "Emp_Name": "Raja kumar",
        "Address": "Madurai",
        "Date_Of_Birth": "",
        "Desig_Name": "Mason Helper",
        "Desig_Description": "Mason Helper",
        "SalaryBasis": "Weekly",
        "FixedSalary": "105.00"
    }, {
        "Emp_Id": "9",
        "Identity_No": "",
        "Emp_Name": "Lakshmi",
        "Address": "Madurai",
        "Date_Of_Birth": "",
        "Desig_Name": "Mason Helper",
        "Desig_Description": "Mason Helper",
        "SalaryBasis": "Weekly",
        "FixedSalary": "100.00"
    }, {
        "Emp_Id": "10",
        "Identity_No": "",
        "Emp_Name": "Palani",
        "Address": "Madurai",
        "Date_Of_Birth": "",
        "Desig_Name": "Carpenter",
        "Desig_Description": "Carpenter",
        "SalaryBasis": "Weekly",
        "FixedSalary": "200.00"
    }, {
        "Emp_Id": "11",
        "Identity_No": "",
        "Emp_Name": "Annamalai",
        "Address": "Madurai",
        "Date_Of_Birth": "",
        "Desig_Name": "Carpenter",
        "Desig_Description": "Carpenter",
        "SalaryBasis": "Weekly",
        "FixedSalary": "220.00"
    }, {
        "Emp_Id": "12",
        "Identity_No": "",
        "Emp_Name": "David",
        "Address": "Madurai",
        "Date_Of_Birth": "",
        "Desig_Name": "Steel Fixer",
        "Desig_Description": "Steel Fixer",
        "SalaryBasis": "Weekly",
        "FixedSalary": "220.00"
    }, {
        "Emp_Id": "13",
        "Identity_No": "",
        "Emp_Name": "Chandru",
        "Address": "Madurai",
        "Date_Of_Birth": "",
        "Desig_Name": "Steel Fixer",
        "Desig_Description": "Steel Fixer",
        "SalaryBasis": "Weekly",
        "FixedSalary": "220.00"
    }, {
        "Emp_Id": "14",
        "Identity_No": "",
        "Emp_Name": "Mani",
        "Address": "Madurai",
        "Date_Of_Birth": "",
        "Desig_Name": "Steel Helper",
        "Desig_Description": "Steel Helper",
        "SalaryBasis": "Weekly",
        "FixedSalary": "175.00"
    }, {
        "Emp_Id": "15",
        "Identity_No": "",
        "Emp_Name": "Karthik",
        "Address": "Madurai",
        "Date_Of_Birth": "",
        "Desig_Name": "Wood Fixer",
        "Desig_Description": "Wood Fixer",
        "SalaryBasis": "Weekly",
        "FixedSalary": "195.00"
    }, {
        "Emp_Id": "16",
        "Identity_No": "",
        "Emp_Name": "Bala",
        "Address": "Madurai",
        "Date_Of_Birth": "",
        "Desig_Name": "Wood Fixer",
        "Desig_Description": "Wood Fixer",
        "SalaryBasis": "Weekly",
        "FixedSalary": "185.00"
    }, {
        "Emp_Id": "17",
        "Identity_No": "",
        "Emp_Name": "Tamil arasi",
        "Address": "Madurai",
        "Date_Of_Birth": "",
        "Desig_Name": "Wood Helper",
        "Desig_Description": "Wood Helper",
        "SalaryBasis": "Weekly",
        "FixedSalary": "185.00"
    }, {
        "Emp_Id": "18",
        "Identity_No": "",
        "Emp_Name": "Perumal",
        "Address": "Madurai",
        "Date_Of_Birth": "",
        "Desig_Name": "Cook",
        "Desig_Description": "Cook",
        "SalaryBasis": "Weekly",
        "FixedSalary": "105.00"
    }, {
        "Emp_Id": "19",
        "Identity_No": "",
        "Emp_Name": "Andiappan",
        "Address": "Madurai",
        "Date_Of_Birth": "",
        "Desig_Name": "Watchman",
        "Desig_Description": "Watchman",
        "SalaryBasis": "Weekly",
        "FixedSalary": "150.00"
    }]
}
```

> **See additional answers to duplicate of this question:**
>
> [How to use jQuery to paginate JSON data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507844/how-to-use-jquery-to-paginate-json-data)

Comment: This question is a duplicate [or duplicated, whatever :)]. I elaborated on that a lot already. [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521372/paging-through-recordsjson-data-using-jquery/2522370#2522370)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use jQuery to paginate JSON data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507844/how-to-use-jquery-to-paginate-json-data)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Duplicate question, duplicate anwser...

You can use the jQuery Pagination plugin:

http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm

(Download it [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination))

---

Here is one way (of several different) how you can use the plugin.

**Step 1:** Generate markup from your JSON-data like the following:

```
<div id="display">
    <!-- This is the div where the visible page will be displayed -->
</div>

<div id="hiddenData">
    <!-- This is the div where you output your records -->
    <div class="record">
        <!-- create one record-div for each record you have in your JSON data -->
    </div>
    <div class="record">
    </div>
</div>
```

The idea is to copy the respective record to the display div when clicking on a page-link. Therefore, the plugin offers a pageSelect-callback function. **Step 2** is to implement this function, for instance:

```
function pageselectCallback(pageIndex, jq) {
    // Clone the record that should be displayed
    var newContent = $('#hiddenData div.record:eq('+pageIndex+')').clone();
    // Update the display container
    $('#display').empty().append(newContent);
    return false;
}
```

This would mean that you have one page per record. If you want to display multiple records per page, you have to modify the above function accordingly.

**The third and final step** is to initialize the whole thing correctly.

```
function initPagination() {
    // Hide the records... they shouldn't be displayed
    $("#hiddenData").css("display", "none");
    // Get the number of records
    var numEntries = $('#hiddenData div.result').length;
    // Create pagination element
    $("#pagination").pagination(numEntries, {
        num_edge_entries: 2,
        num_display_entries: 8, // number of page links displayed 
        callback: pageselectCallback,
        items_per_page: 1  // Adjust this value if you change the callback!
    });
}
```

So, you just have to generate the HTML markup from your JSON data and call the init-function afterwards.

Comment: Can you explain How to add n number of pagination in same page.

Comment: @Elankeeran I've answered this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605053/two-jquery-pagination-plugin-in-the-same-page-doesnt-seem-to-work/2621617#2621617

Comment: in initPagination function it's div.record instead of div.result, right?

Comment: i tried to use your code but i got this error from the jquery pagination function: "Method 8 does not exist on jQuery.pagination",