# Using array.splice and calculating boundaries javascript json ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, json

So, I'm receiving a json file through ajax and showing it in a table. I want to paginate that array. So here's what I'm doing

```
function Paginator(groups){

   /**
    * This should work.
    * The children() function returns a JQuery object that contains the children.
    * So you just need to check the size and see if it has at least one child.
    * #grouplist > * makes it slightly faster - I think...
    */
   if ( $('#grouplist > *').length > 0 ) {
       $.each($('#grouplist').children(), function(i, current) {
           current.remove();
       });
   }

   //http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-clone-array
   var clone_group = groups.slice(0);
   var page = _globalpage,
   startRec = Math.max(page - 1, 0) * _recPerPage,
   endRec = Math.min(startRec + _recPerPage, clone_group.length)
   recordsToShow = clone_group.splice(startRec, endRec);
   console.log('start '+startRec+' end '+endRec+' page '+ page + ' records to show '+recordsToShow.length);
   // loop through the array to populate your list
   $.each(recordsToShow, function(i, currentGroup){
       console.log('id '+currentGroup.id);
       $('#grouplist').append('<tr> /*html with stuff I need*/ </tr>');
   });
}
```

Probably not good practice but every variable that starts with underscore '_' is globaly defined. The only one that changes is _globalpage that gets incremented or decremented by 1 everytime you hit "previous" or "next".
I'm thinking of changing those to cookies, once I get this to work properly.

This is the result from the console.log

"*start 0 end 10 page 1 records to show 10*"

"*id 1*" through "*id 10*"

*after hitting next*

"*start 10 end 20 page 2 records to show 20*"

"*id 11*" to "*id 30*"

What's wrong with this? Thanks in advance

Comment: This is heavily based on this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2507945

Comment: Write an answer rather than edit your question

Comment: Thanks! It's just the way stackoverflow works and it helps people find useful answers. Maybe your question has a better solution than the one you found - someone probably won't put it there because you've written the solution in the very first post. This way, you can accept your own answer but someone else can write a better solution and I can upvote that one (just for example). You see this happen especially when dealing with errors.

Comment: Right. Good point. I would like some optimizations if any. I just realized I could do $('#id').empty instead of iterating through the children and whatnot. Perhaps using jQuery is more efficient?

Comment: `.empty` will almost certainly be faster but try out "jsperf" or ask another question

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I usually figure this out before I post ... XP
I don't even need to clone the array, all I need is to use array.slice instead of array.splice

solution:

```
var page = _globalpage,
    startRec = Math.max(page - 1, 0) * _recPerPage,
    endRec = Math.min(startRec + _recPerPage, groups.length)
    recordsToShow = groups.slice(startRec, endRec);
$.each(recordsToShow, function(i, currentGroup){ //print stuff
```

Thanks anyway, the collective spirit of the Internet helped even behind the curtains. :P