# How to make pagination with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a pagination for some site and I need to use Ajax for page changing, therefore I need to print links to "1", "2", "3" pages, with "`<a>`" tag. I understand that I need to add Javascript event handler for click by this link, but I needn't that user goes by link, I only need that "1","2","3" look like link. What should I do? Is there any way to make digits look like links? And how can I add Javascript event handler for click by link? Thank you in advance.

Comment: check this thread [pagination-with-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060775/pagination-with-javascript). and search first before post

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242974/ajax-jquery-related-how-to-call-ajax-on-a-ajax-loaded-page/11243250#11243250


Please check this url there is a answer of your questions

Comment: I need also to take information about links.

Comment: Use actual `<a>` tags so that users who don't or can't use a mouse can still use your page. (Your JavaScript code would then intercept the click event and prevent default `<a>` tag behaviour.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of insert  tags, just insert `<span>` tags.
Give them a particular class and then handle click with javascript.

Your html code could looks like:

```
<span class="my_link">1</span> <span class="my_link">2</span> <span class="my_link">3</span>
```

In your css you can isert the link-style hand on hover with the rule:

```
.my-link { cursor: pointer }
```

and then, with JS and jQuery, handle the click

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.my-link').click(function(){ #your stuff...  });
</script>
```