# Generate page numbers using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, pager

How to generate page numbers like the below using javascript/jquery?

If the 5 th page is selected i have to show 3,4 and 6,7 and also 1,last page with prev,next...
Any suggestion....

**EDIT:**

How to work with json data that use these pagination div? (ie) My json data contains 50 records
I want to 10 in page 1 and so on... How to paginate json data with these numbers...

I want a jquery function to pass `currentpageno,lastpagenumber` and the function should generate me page numbers like the below for me

If it is the first page

[image: istpage]

If it is in the middle,

[image: Pager]

If it is the last page,

[image: lastpage]

**Second EDIT:**

I have tried this function but doesn't seem to get the desired result

```
function generatePages(currentPage, LastPage) {
    if (LastPage <= 5) {
        var pages = '';
        for(var i=1;i<=5;i++)
        {
            pages += "<a class='page-numbers' href='#'>" + i + "</a>"
        }
        $("#PagerDiv").append(pages);
    }
    if (LastPage > 5) {
        var pages = '';
        for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            pages += "<a class='page-numbers' href='#'>" + i + "</a>"
        }
        $("#PagerDiv").append(pages);
    }
}
```

I have the `lastPage` and `currentPage` values please help me out getting this...

Comment: You need to writ some actual code, on your own, probably using a `for` loop.

Comment: @SLaks: lol'd. But actually, that isn't true either :D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "pagination" and there's (as always) a jQuery plugin that does the job for you:

http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm

(Download it [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination))

---

**Edit:** Since you don't seem to be able to get it working, here is one way (of several different) how you can use the plugin.

**Step 1:** Generate markup from your JSON-data like the following:

```
<div id="display">
    <!-- This is the div where the visible page will be displayed -->
</div>

<div id="hiddenData">
    <!-- This is the div where you output your records -->
    <div class="record">
        <!-- create one record-div for each record you have in your JSON data -->
    </div>
    <div class="record">
    </div>
</div>
```

The idea is to copy the respective record to the display div when clicking on a page-link. Therefore, the plugin offers a pageSelect-callback function. **Step 2** is to implement this function, for instance:

```
function pageselectCallback(pageIndex, jq){
    // Clone the record that should be displayed
    var newContent = $('#hiddenData div.record:eq('+pageIndex+')').clone();
    // Update the display container
    $('#display').empty().append(newContent);
    return false;
}
```

This would mean that you have one page per record. If you want to display multiple records per page, you have to modify the above function accordingly.

**The third and final step** is to initialize the whole thing correctly.

```
function initPagination() {
    // Hide the records... they shouldn't be displayed
    $("#hiddenData").css("display", "none");
    // Get the number of records
    var numEntries = $('#hiddenData div.result').length;
    // Create pagination element
    $("#pagination").pagination(numEntries, {
        num_edge_entries: 2,
        num_display_entries: 8, // number of page links displayed 
        callback: pageselectCallback,
        items_per_page: 1  // Adjust this value if you change the callback!
    });
}
```

So, you just have to generate the HTML markup from your JSON data and call the init-function afterwards.

It's not that difficult, is it?

Comment: json doesn't make any difference, so yes, it will work. Have a look at the sources of the demo page (the members.js, specifically). It shows you how to load data on demand...

Comment: @Mef documentation would be useful?

Comment: @Mef one more issue with pagination plugin... Please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551146/callback-function-in-jquery-doesnt-seem-to-work

Answer (score 2):

yeah @SLaks is right. nothing too crazy here. You will have 2 variables currentPageNumber and lastPageNumber.

```
$("div.paginator").append("<a...>prev</a>");
$("div.paginator").append("<a...>1</a>");

for (x = (currentPageNumber - 2; x <= (currentPageNumber + 2); x++) {
    $("div.paginator").append("<a...>"+ x +"</a>");
} 

$("div.paginator").append("<a...>"+ lastPageNumber +"</a>");
$("div.paginator").append("<a...>next</a>");

// you could apply styles to and a tag in the div.paginator
// you could apply a special class to the a tag that matches the currentPageNumber 
// you can also bind some click events to each a tag and use the $(this).text() to grab the number of the page to go to
```

Comment: Yeah, or you could just do what @Mef said. That is pretty dope. Welcome to the days of not having to write you own code. Community/Social Programming ROCKS!

Comment: However, the most essential part is missing here. Where do the page numbers come from?

Comment: @Mef i use asp.net and i move my values using a hiddenfield and fetch them in jquery...

Comment: oh, I didn't mean you, actually I referred to the sample code which is of course right, but covers only a very small part of the problem

Comment: @Mef i tried your and got this...http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/9509/pager2.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Use [THIS](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-pagination) or [THAT](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jPaginate) plugin. They're both easy html pagination plugins. Put everything in the html at once and paginate with one of those.

Answer (score 1):

Add two new hidden inputs

```
<input type='hidden' id='current_page' />  
<input type='hidden' id='show_per_page' />
```

Next add an empty div to create pagination controls

```
<!-- An empty div which will be populated using jQuery -->  
<div id='page_navigation'></div>

$(document).ready(function(){

    //how much items per page to show
    var show_per_page = 5;
    //getting the amount of elements inside content div
    var number_of_items = $('#content').children().size();
    //calculate the number of pages we are going to have
    var number_of_pages = Math.ceil(number_of_items/show_per_page);

    //set the value of our hidden input fields
    $('#current_page').val(0);
    $('#show_per_page').val(show_per_page);

    //now when we got all we need for the navigation let's make it '

    /*
    what are we going to have in the navigation?
        - link to previous page
        - links to specific pages
        - link to next page
    */
    var navigation_html = '<a class="previous_link" href="javascript:previous();">Prev</a>';
    var current_link = 0;
    while(number_of_pages > current_link){
        navigation_html += '<a class="page_link" href="javascript:go_to_page(' + current_link +')" longdesc="' + current_link +'">'+ (current_link + 1) +'</a>';
        current_link++;
    }
    navigation_html += '<a class="next_link" href="javascript:next();">Next</a>';

    $('#page_navigation').html(navigation_html);

    //add active_page class to the first page link
    $('#page_navigation .page_link:first').addClass('active_page');

    //hide all the elements inside content div
    $('#content').children().css('display', 'none');

    //and show the first n (show_per_page) elements
    $('#content').children().slice(0, show_per_page).css('display', 'block');

});

function previous(){

    new_page = parseInt($('#current_page').val()) - 1;
    //if there is an item before the current active link run the function
    if($('.active_page').prev('.page_link').length==true){
        go_to_page(new_page);
    }

}

function next(){
    new_page = parseInt($('#current_page').val()) + 1;
    //if there is an item after the current active link run the function
    if($('.active_page').next('.page_link').length==true){
        go_to_page(new_page);
    }

}
function go_to_page(page_num){
    //get the number of items shown per page
    var show_per_page = parseInt($('#show_per_page').val());

    //get the element number where to start the slice from
    start_from = page_num * show_per_page;

    //get the element number where to end the slice
    end_on = start_from + show_per_page;

    //hide all children elements of content div, get specific items and show them
    $('#content').children().css('display', 'none').slice(start_from, end_on).css('display', 'block');

    /*get the page link that has longdesc attribute of the current page and add active_page class to it
    and remove that class from previously active page link*/
    $('.page_link[longdesc=' + page_num +']').addClass('active_page').siblings('.active_page').removeClass('active_page');

    //update the current page input field
    $('#current_page').val(page_num);
}
```