# How to create pagination like Stack Overflow site

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

how to create pagination like stackoverflow?

Comment: Why specifically Stack Overflow? Does it do something different to any other form of pagination?

Comment: As far as I can see, Stack Overflow's pagination is entirely server-side: it's got nothing to do with Javascript or jQuery.

Comment: its client-side pagination, if you disable javascript in your browser 
you can see this message "Stack Overflow works best with JavaScript enabled" and all pages show in one page

Comment: @user1400: While it does display that message when javascript is disabled, pagination still works.

Comment: Obviously, it is not downloading 600k questions to the browser.

Comment: @codeka, you are right ,when JavaScript is disable, pagination works

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523075/generate-page-numbers-using-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't say what server side technology you are using but if you want a pure client side solution you may take a look at the [jQuery Pagination](http://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/) plugin. Here's a [demo page](http://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/#demo).

Answer (score 2):

Just include jquery and jquery pagination plugin in your page and use this,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".pager").pagination(300, {
    callback: pagecallback,
    current_page: 0,
    items_per_page: 5,
    num_display_entries: 5,
    next_text: 'Next',
    prev_text: 'Prev',
    num_edge_entries: 1
  });
});
```

```css
.pager {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.page-numbers {
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  color: #808185;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 130%;
  margin-right: 3px;
  padding: 4px 4px 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.page-numbers.desc {
  border: medium none;
}
.page-numbers:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.pager a {
  color: #808185;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
.pager a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.pager a:visited {
  color: #808185;
  outline: none;
}
.page-numbers.next,
.page-numbers.prev {
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
.page-numbers.current {
  background-color: #808185;
  border: 1px solid #808185;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.page-numbers.dots {
  border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pager" id="Pagination">
  <!-- the container for your first pagination area -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery plugin pagination:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination

Comment: Oh ok fine. I check only on jquery pagination link it give different url so only i provide the jquery main plugins url.  Now i verified it is demo page link.  Ok fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can create pagination using [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination) with less than 10 line of code like this
 [image: example of pagination using twitter bootstrap]

Answer (score 0):

[This works very great for me. Since this is no javascript, users with javascript disabled can use it too.](http://www.phpjabbers.com/php--mysql-select-data-and-split-on-pages-php25.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function too:

```
function makePaging(totalPages, pageIndex) {
    var oPaging, i, j, k;
    var totalPages = parseInt(totalPages);

    pageIndex++;

    i = pageIndex;
    j = pageIndex - 1;
    k = pageIndex + 1;

    var oBefore, oAfter;
    oBefore = "";
    oAfter = "";

    while (j != 0 && j != i - 6) {
        oBefore = "<a class='Page' href='#' data-index='" + (j - 1) + "'>" + j + "</a>&nbsp;" + oBefore;
        j--;
    }

    for (; k < totalPages + 1 && k < i + 6; k++) {
        oAfter += "<a class='Page' href='#' data-index='" + (k - 1) + "'>" + k + "</a>&nbsp;";
    }

    oPaging = oBefore + "<a class='CurPage' href='#' rel='' style='color:Red;'>" + i.toString() + "</a>&nbsp;" + oAfter;

    return oPaging;
}
```