# Pagination Numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

Ive recently added a pagination to my site - Code Below
It works however everytime i had more content it obviously adds a new number to the seqeunce. The problem i have is the numbers arent getting to a certain point and stopping they are just constantly filling up the bottom of the page.

Does anybody know how i can alter my code so say only 5 numbers are visible until i start moving further down line ie. if i was on number 1 it would display to 5, then when i was on 5 it would display to 10 etc.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you

```
(function($) {

 // all content number 
var totalContent = $("section").length;
  // post number in a page
var onePageContent = 9;,

  //Page number and Math.round for balancing page
  $("section:gt(" + (onePageContent - 1) + ")").hide();
var totalPage = Math.round(totalContent / onePageContent);

  // create page link
  for(i= 1; i <= totalPage; i++) {    
    $(".pagination").append("<li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>" + i + "</a></li>");
  }

  // first page added active class
  $(".pagination li:first").addClass("active");

  // click function
  $(".pagination li").on("click", function() {

      var index = $(this).index() + 1;
      var gt = onePageContent * index;

      $(".pagination li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");    
      $("section").hide();

      for(i = gt - onePageContent; i < gt; i++) {      
        $("section:eq(" + i + ")").show();
      }       
      }); 
 })($);
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672609/how-to-create-pagination-like-stack-overflow-site

Comment: you should use Math.ceil() instead of Math.round to get the total nbr of Pages. ceil() always rounds up. round() can also round down and therefore prevent you from getting some contents...