# Problem displaying dynamically generated records with client-side paging using jQuery Templates plugin & Pagination plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

For a custom requirement to display dynamically generated records with client-side paging, I'm using [Microsoft's jQuery Templates plugin](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/10/05/jquery-templates-on-microsoft-ajax-cdn.aspx) alongwith [G Birke's jQuery Pagination plugin](https://github.com/gbirke/jquery_pagination). I could have managed with just the Pagination plugin but now definitely need the Template plugin to conserve on server side processing involved in generating records with formatting.

I've shared [my code sample on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ebepa3/2) ([see source](http://jsbin.com/ebepa3/2/edit)). This sample is an adaption of [Stephen Walther's Templates plugin example](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/10/05/jquery-templates-on-microsoft-ajax-cdn.aspx) & a [Pagination plugin example](http://jsbin.com/upuwe) by [StackOverflow member brianpeiris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523163/jquery-pagination-plugin/1523265#1523265)

```
$("#flickr").live("click", function() {
    var url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/groups_pool.gne?id=44124373027@N01&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?";
        // Grab some flickr images of cats
        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            // Format the data using the catTemplate template
            $("#catTemplate").tmpl(data.items).appendTo("#hiddenresult");
        });
    alert("Total flickr records fetched =" + $('#hiddenresult div.result').length);
    initPagination();

 });
```

The problems are:

1. The records show up with paging in Firefox & IE8 only if the alert in the code above is present. The alert probably introduces a delay. How to fix the code so that it works without that alert?
2. Even if the alert is present, the sample doesn't work in Chrome, Safari & Opera. How to make the solution cross-browser?

I'll appreciate if anyone can help me fix these issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thoink you need to move your initPagination() function call into the callback function of the getjson function right underneath where you append the template to the dom.